# Scheme - from list to list of lists

Tags: scheme

I have 2 lists: 
a = `(mn (5) (1 2))`
b = `(hl (3) (8 4))`

I try to get: `((mn (5) (1 2)) (hl (3) (8 4)))`. (meaning a b)

When I try append, It gives me: `(mn (5) (1 2) hl (3) (8 4))`.

When I try cons, It gives me: `((mn (5) (1 2)) hl (3) (8 4))`.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `(list a b)`. In your case it will be:

```
(list '(mn (5) (1 2)) '(hl (3) (8 4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You apparently want a list of lists.  It's been a while since I've done scheme, but the easiest thing I can remember to do would be `(cons a (cons b ()))`  where `a` and `b` are references to the separate lists and `()` is the nil terminator.

I hope I'm not just doing your homework for you :-P